# What is the difference between Aurelia Plugin and Feature?

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to register a couple of plugins for my app however I am not sure how this should be done.

The plugins that I have, include two `ValueConverters` and the [`gooy/aurelia-animator-tinyanimate`](https://github.com/gooy/aurelia-animator-tinyanimate) which I have installed via `JSPM`.

Here is my current implementation:

**resources\index.ts/js**

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.globalResources('../from-now', '../date-format');
}
```

**main.ts/js** (this is the entry point of the app)

```
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia): void {
        aurelia.use
            .standardConfiguration()
            .developmentLogging()
            .plugin('resources/index', 'gooy/aurelia-animator-tinyanimate'); 

        aurelia.start().then(function () { return aurelia.setRoot('views/app'); });
}
```

The converters are working however I do not see the `tinyanimate` to be loaded.

Based on the above, I have the following questions:

1. how would I move the `gooy/aurelia-animator-tinyanimate` over to the `index.js` file?
2. what is the difference between `plugin()` and `feature()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Features are basically the same as a plugin, except that they live in your own source tree. Based on your `index.js` file, you would need to load your feature like this:

```
aurelia.use.feature('resources`);
```

Assuming that the feature's `index.js` file is located in the `resources` folder. You may want to change your `index.js` file to

```
export function configure(config) {
  config.globalResources('./from-now', './date-format');
}
```

and update your directory structure to put `from-now.js` and `date-format.js` in the `resources` directory. You don't need to do this, but from an organizational standpoint, it would make sense. Changing the parameter name is simply to better describe what the parameter is (a FrameworkConfiguration instance).

To load `gooy/aurelia-animator-tinyanimate` in your `main.js` file, you will need to remove the `'resources/index'` parameter from the call to `plugin`. Aurelia will then load the plugin properly for you.  Your `main.js` file should end up looking like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia): void {
        aurelia.use
            .standardConfiguration()
            .developmentLogging()
            .feature('resources')
            .plugin('gooy/aurelia-animator-tinyanimate'); 

        aurelia.start().then(function () { return aurelia.setRoot('views/app'); });
}
```

Also, note that there is no need for the `import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';` line in your main.ts.

Comment: Tried above and got 404 errors looking for .html view for each class in resources.  Needed to add `import {noView} from 'aurelia-framework';
@noView` decorator to prevent it from looking for html view.